# how to bookmark a dynamically created aspx page?

Tags: java, asp.net, parameters

There is this site wich in the address bar only shows like "http://example.com/examplepage.aspx".
Normally if it would have parameters behind it you probably could just copy that one.
But since it doesn't, how do i bookmark this page.
It doesn't necessarily have to be a bookmark, but at least an easy way to access the page.
(fyi I know basic HTML and Java, maybe it's only possible programmatically).
thnx

Answer (score 1):

Generally dynamic pages (taking in context with the question) are not book mark friendly.

You could probably sniff the incoming request, and create a fake form which you can then submit later.

However there may be situations where there are parameters such as session id which are valid for only small periods of time.
 
You should read up on sessions. In really simple terms, a session is assigned to users accessing a website. They have an expiry period. IF you stay idle beyond  set time (determined by the developer) you will not be able to get in. And every time you log back in, you may be assign a new session.

You would have noticed, that some websites automatically log you in, this is mostly done with the help of cookies. Cookies work in tandem with sessions, they store very basic information, so the next time you come back to a website, it will be able to identify you as a returning user and provide you with access.

Then again, some pages don't use sessions, they might have their own custom way of identifying users.

Bookmarks can be used in dynamic pages, if the code allows you to send GET requests, if they don't have any other extra parameters which will block you.

To Summarize:

- Dynamic page not very bookmark friendly.
- There may be parameters used to access a webpage which change constantly, which you cannot really save.
- You may be able to get into dynamic pages using bookmarks, if they don't use any of the dynamically changing parameters.

Since you know Java, you should probably read up on JSPs/servlets to get an understanding of what happens behind the scenes in dynamic pages.

Hope this answers your questions.